# In regularised regression, why not penalise higher degree coefficients more?

Tags: regression, regularization

for the case of fitting a polynomial to data ($y = a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}+...+a_{n}x^{n}$) with regularisation of the coefficients, I'm wondering why are all of the coefficients usually penalised by the same amount i.e. the regularisation part of the cost function is something like $\lambda \sum_{n} a_{n}^{2}$? My intuition is that if I have a linear and a quadratic model, say, that have the same predictive skill on the training data, then I would prefer the linear model. So then having positive $a_{2}$ values should be penalised more than having positive $a_{1}$ values. Is there a reason why this is not usually done? I thought it might be because people don't want to have to set more than one regularisation parameter, but it wouldn't be necessary to do this if a penalty term like $\lambda \sum_{n} n a_{n}^{2}$ were used instead.

Comment: You're welcome to weight the penalty, but that begs the question of *how would you choose the weights*?  The form of weights suggested at the end of your question can be accommodated simply by what basis you use for the polynomials.  *E.g.*, instead of using $(1,x,x^2,\ldots, x^n)$ you could use $(1,x, x^2/\sqrt{2},\ldots, x^n/\sqrt{n})$ to weight the higher terms in exactly the amounts given by your example penalty.  Thus, this kind of weighting is already accommodated in the standard theory.  What other forms of weighting would you have in mind?

Comment: Rather than deciding you prefer linear...I think you get much of the benefit by rescaling the monomials to mean 0, sd 1. The problem with monomials  is the higher order terms grow so fast, so even a small weight has a big impact on the shape of regression...therefore unless you normalise, the standard regularisation will have little impact (since your weights on your higher order terms will be small in any case)

Comment: What if you have square root and linear?  Do you still prefer linear?  What if the variable being so transformed were the square of some other variable?

Comment: Something like this is indeed being done, see Nicholson, W. B.; Bien, J. and Matteson, D. S. (2016), “High dimensional forecasting via interpretable vector autoregression,” arXiv, 1412.5250v2. The same idea is implemented in the [`bigtime`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigtime/index.html) package in R.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

@whuber Yes I agree you could also scale the inputs to the regression. This is also not usually done in examples of regularised regression I see online, though, and I've never seen it suggested. I'm basically wondering is there a reason why e.g. people have tried this and found that it gives little benefit typically?

Comment: @seanv507 Yes rescaling could help, but it still doesn't seem to me that it would encode a typical preference for models with terms of lower order.

Comment: @TheLaconic It's a good point that it is not clear if there is a general rule that would work sensibly for fractional powers. But at least for regression against integer powers of an independent variable, which is commonly done, I would have thought there are some simple weightings that could be experimented with. ..

Comment: @TheLaconic ...If there is just one independent variable $x$, I don't think it would matter if it is the square of something else ($z$) for the penalty term I suggested (the coefficient in front of $x^{2}$ would be penalised twice as much as that in front of $x$ regardless of whether it is substituted by $z$).

Comment: @whuber Coming back to your first question "how would you choose the weights?" - I agree this is key. I'm wondering has work been done to establish that penalising all coefficients equally (choosing all weights to be 1) works best or is it a fairly arbitrary choice? If the latter, it would seem interesting to explore other options. The choice made for the standard regularisation term of setting all weights to be 1 also seems to need justifying if it is to be used in preference to other choices.

Comment: Good points all.  Clearly the choice is arbitrary because it depends on what basis one chooses for the model matrix.  An effort to standardize that basis (which is routinely and automatically done in linear modeling) or even orthonormalize it would likely help for many nonlinear models.  The justification for that rests on (a) approximating the nonlinear model with a linear one in a neighborhood of its solution and (b) inspecting formulas for standard errors of estimate in the linear case.